# Full screen camera on an ionic app

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have an application based on Ionic.
At a part of it, I need to display a full screen div containing the camera input and, on top of it, a png guide.

So far, I've achieved our purpose by using lots of jQuery, but now I'm wondering if there's a better way. I mean, some way to just play with some css to make Ionic let me display a full screen div on top of everything (navigation bar included).

I've tried some like this:

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

But using this CSS, the .container div, has 0 width and it's not positioning on top of everything.

Any ideas?

Comment: have your tried using height:100vh;width:100vw

Comment: Actually I found out that there's no way to do what I wanted. Since the cordova plugin opens another app, and only gives me the option to place it bellow or on top of my Ionic app. So... lots of jQuery it is